# How to insert unique value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload data from cvs file to mysql. I want to filter the duplicate values of column roll. 
for eg.

```
Table1 
-----------
 id  name    roll
 1  Nirdos    4  
 2  krishn    2 
 3  shrest    2
```

If data is like this I want to insert first 2 rows because third row have duplicate row with second row.

**Thnks In Advance**

Comment: you can just put a UNIQUE index on column `roll`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement to do the insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO targetTable (id, name, roll)
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.roll 
FROM sourceTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT roll, MIN(id) AS min_id
      FROM sourceTable
      GROUP BY roll) AS t2
ON t1.roll = t2.roll AND t1.id = t2.min_id
```

In case of a duplicate `roll` value, this query will insert the record having the minimum `id` value.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL database provides a facility where you can make the roll column unique, and the database itself won't take duplicate input for that particular column.

The second method would be to check for duplicate entries before entering a new row and match the data with the data you are about to enter